# В чем ошибка при использовании ExecutorService?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Вкратце о том,что я пытался сделать в коде, который приведен ниже. Хотел сделать парсер баз данных формата csv большого размера. Я решил использовать апачиевскую библиотеку и реализовать следующий алгоритм:
1 Начинается считывание поэлементное из базы и это складируется в коллекцию
2 По достижения определенного размера считывание приостанавливается и коллекция проверяется регуляркой. 
3 РВ проверяет строки на наличие мейл-адреса и пишет это в текстовый документ.
Далее,чтобы ускорить процесс я решил сделать тред пулл. Прочитал,что есть пакет Concurrent, который с помощью интерфейса ExecutorService позволяет создавать пулл потоков. И алгоритм сформулировал следующий:
Начинается все как и раньше,заполняется коллекция, далее она передается воркеру в один из потоков пулла, и там он ее проверяет регуляркой. 
Согласно моему плану воркеры должны параллельно друг другу получать и  парсить элементы коллекций,однако все происходит последовательно.Если есть поток, который занят обработкой большого массива данных, то параллельно ему другие не стартуют. Вот что выводится при компиляции:

```
Worker 1 started
Thread 1 stopped
Worker 2 started
Thread 2 stopped
Worker 3 started
```

На 3 воркере поток принимает поллекцию в которой происходит длительная проверка моей базы и зверски думает. Параллельно по идее должен стартовать 4,5 и т.д. потоки в пуле,но этого не происходит. Не до конца я по видимому понял как работать с этим пакетом...подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть косяк.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class TestThreadPool {

    static int executorInProgressCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);//creating a pool of 5 threads

        String path = "DB adres.csv";
        Reader in = new FileReader(path);

        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.MYSQL.parse(in);
        List<CSVRecord> tableStr = new ArrayList<>();

        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            tableStr.add(record);
            if (tableStr.size() == 5  ) {
                Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(tableStr);
                executor.execute(worker);
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Класс "воркеров":

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
     static int docNum=1;
    static int workerCount=0;
     List<CSVRecord> lineList=new ArrayList<>();

    static public final Pattern PATTERN_MAIL = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9_-]+\\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,6}");
    Matcher getMail;

    public WorkerThread(List<CSVRecord> list){
        this.lineList=list;
    }

    public void run() {
        workerCount++;
        System.out.println("Worker "+workerCount+" started");
        File file = new File("doc name " + docNum + ".text");
        docNum++;
        try {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            for (int i = 0; i < lineList.size(); i++) {
                getMail = PATTERN_MAIL.matcher(lineList.get(i).toString());
                while (getMail.find()) {
                    bufWriter.write(lineList.get(i).toString().substring(getMail.start(), getMail.end()) + ";");
                }
            }
            lineList.clear();
            bufWriter.close();
            System.out.println("Thread "+ workerCount+" stopped");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error occured in creating the file");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкция

```
if (tableStr.size() == 5  ) {
```

выполнится только один раз, потому что коллекция продолжит пухнуть(как там появилось три воркера - я, если честно, не понимаю). Кроме того,

```
executor.shutdown();
```

вызовется сразу после того, как будут прочитаны (но не обязательно обработаны) все записи, а в разные воркеры будет передаваться одна и та же коллекция, и воркеры будут производить одну и ту же работу

В целом, вам лучше использовать очереди для передачи данных между тредами.

Comment: вот что значит взгляд со стороны. насчет коллекции вы были правы, я не предусмотрел этот момент. Поставил tableStr.clear(); после  executor.execute(worker); и дело сдвинулось с мертвой точки,однако еще есть над чем работать.Вы написали,что во все воркеры будет передаваться одна и таже коллекция. Почему?там же будет очистка коллекции после передачи.И насчет очередей. я так понимаю вы имели в виду коллекцию Queue? В чем ее преимущество?

Comment: *Вы написали,что во все воркеры будет передаваться одна и таже коллекция. Почему?там же будет очистка коллекции после передачи* - потому что вы передаете один и тот же объект. В многопоточной среде порядок действий не гарантирован, и практически гарантированно некоторые потоки будут видеть одно и то же. *И насчет очередей. я так понимаю вы имели в виду коллекцию Queue? В чем ее преимущество?* - В том, что вместо передачи коллекций элементов вы можете передавать элементы по одному, и вместо того, чтобы вручную разбивать нагрузку, можно предоставить это очереди.

Comment: понял к чему вы клоните.хорошая идея. я посмотрел и обнаружил в concurrent прикольную штуку- http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html
наверное попробую придумать что-то с ней. большое спасибо за рекомендации.вы мне помогли